# Make sure things run only once in componentDidUpdate() and componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reactjs

If I have a method that initialized something (like a jQuery widget), how can I make sure that the initialize gets called only once, but gets called for both refreshes and for when one navigates to that page without refresh. My current approach is the below:

```
//  key used to make sure initialize() only runs in one of DidUpdate/DidMount
let key = 0;

Component = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  hasKey() {
    return key;
  },
  getKey() {
    key = 1;
  },
  resetKey() {
    key = 0;
  },
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!(this.hasKey())) {
      initialize()();
      this.getKey();
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!(this.hasKey())) {
      initialize()();
      this.getKey();
    }
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.resetKey();
  }
}})
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, including your initializer once in `componentDidMount` should be all you need.  This function only runs once - when the component gets mounted to the DOM.  Refreshing the page or navigating to the page will cause this component to mount, thus triggering your initializer function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may create properties into constructor by default = false, eg. didMount, didUpdate. And componentDidMount will be called only once so you can put `this.didMount = true`;
The componentDidUpdate will be called each time after updating, so you mast check: `!this.didUpdate = (this.didUpdate = true);`
And then check only these properties;